In function 'int main()' : function-definition is not allowed
TryCPP.cpp: In function 'int main()':
TryCPP.cpp:_:41: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
   void send_massage_func(string message){ cout << message << endl; }
                                         ^

I only just put function & run in vscode without any function run well only those function under main() show error, not global function.
As Output say not allow before "token", what is "token"?
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() { cout << "C++ Version : " << __cplusplus << endl;//C++ Version : 201402
  void send_massage_func(string message) { cout << message << endl; }/*this line*/

  return 0;
}

Whats wrong with is any other problem like g++, clang or #include liberary i don't know please help

Functions can't be defined inside other functions in C++. You can't nest functions. A function must be defined at namespace scope.

It is possible to declare a local lambda function, using a slightly different syntax auto send_message_func = [](string message) { cout << message << endl; };  See Introduction to lambdas (anonymous functions)

"what is 'token'?" -- See A: What is a Token in C++? (To understand your error message, you can ignore the word "token"; the compiler determined that there is a syntax error at the {; it does not matter if you want to call it the { character or the { token.)

The issue in your code is that you are trying to define a function (send_massage_func) inside the main function. In C++, functions cannot be defined inside other functions; they need to be defined outside of any function or class scope.
Here's a corrected version of your code where the send_massage_func function is defined outside of
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 void send_massage_func(string message) {
    cout << message << endl;
 }

 int main() {
   cout << "C++ Version : " << __cplusplus << endl;

   send_massage_func("Hello from send_massage_func!");

   return 0;
 }

Explanation:
Function Definition: The function send_massage_func is defined outside of main. This is the correct place to define functions that you want to call from within main or other functions.
Function Call: Inside main, you can call send_massage_func to use the function.
Regarding the term "token" in the error message: in this context, "token" generally refers to a syntactical unit in the code. The error message is indicating that there's a syntax issue (an unexpected token or symbol) at the point where the compiler encountered the void send_massage_func(string message) definition.
